# cmd Error : Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, cmd

Have tried solutions given on many threads but not able to figure out what's wrong with my code:

B.java is at **C:\com\check2\pkgs2\B.java**

```
System PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
```

CMD Status :

```
C:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
%CLASSPATH%

C:\>javac com\check2\pkgs2\B.java

C:\>java com\check2\pkgs2\B.class
Error: Could not find or load main class com\check2\pkgs2\B.class
```

B.java is getting compiled successfully and .class is getting created. but not able to execute. What is the problem? Please help me out.

> OS: Windows 7
>
> Java version: 1.7.0_51
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment: build 1.7.0_51-b13

Comment: how did you compile your code?

Comment: C:\>javac com\check2\pkgs2\B.java

Comment: Duplicate of *lots* of questions. Just trying to find the best one now. Basically, you want `java com.check2.pkgs2.B`

Comment: Actually, you want `java -cp . com.check2.pkgs2.B`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon Skeet, it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

To compile:

```
C:\>javac -d . com\check2\pkgs2\B.java
```

To run:

```
C:\>java -cp . com.check2.pkgs2.B
```

Comment: No, that's not how you run it... you specify a *class name*.